# Give "Qualify lead button" functionality in On Lead Form

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm-2013, microsoft-dynamics

I have created custom ribbon Button On Lead Form. I want to give "Qualify lead button" functionality. How to do?

Answer (score 1):

`Qualify Lead Button` is already there, why you want to replicate that ?
  you can call `Custom Workflow` on ribbon button click,
https://ribbonworkbench.uservoice.com/knowledgebase/articles/132235-create-a-workflow-short-cut-ribbon-button-no-code

and do the required action in workflow. Create `Account` from `account details` section in `Lead` and `Contact` from `contact details` in Lead. At the end `Qualify the lead`.

You can also call the function, that is called behind the 'Qualify' ribbon button of `Lead`

```
FunctionName:  Mscrm.LeadCommandActions.qualifyLeadQuick
Library:       $webresource:Lead_main_system_library.js
```